# Load Large image asynchronously into photo album like view

Tags: ios, asynchronous, load, uiimage

I'm trying to make view like photo album. but image file is quite big (2048x1536, png). It takes quite time to load several images. So made thread for loading images..
At first..make UIButton for image holder.

```
UIButton* thumbnail = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:r];
[[self scroll] addSubview:thumbnail];
[thumbnail release];
```

and start thread for image loading

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(th_load_filelist) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

thread is here

```
-(void) th_load_filelist
{
   NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    
   for (UIButton* bt in [self.scroll subviews])
   {
      UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString*)bt.tag];
      [[bt layer] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContents:) withObject:(id)[img CGImage] waitUntilDone:YES];
      [img release];
   }

   [pool release];
}
```

It works well. in normal situation.
But If there are many images and memory warning happends.
App is crashed without any error message.
Could you give me tip to fix it ?
I suspect there is memory problem caused by large images..

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't loading sync vs async, it's the amount of pixels you are loading into memory. Your app is being killed by the system because it is using too much memory.

To solve this problem, I would have the server provide both a 1:1 size image(320x480 for non-retina iphone) and then a larger image which would not be loaded into memory. I would then only load the larger image into memory(such as a UIImage) if I needed it(zooming in or showing on higher resolution screen).

Comment: Here are more ideas on how to solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679457/app-crashing-when-using-large-images-on-ios-4-0