# UIImageView+AFNetworking on device memory problems for large images (leak?)

Tags: ios, memory, uiimageview, afnetworking

I've been having issues loading [this 2.8MB image](http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/712130main_8246931247_e60f3c09fb_o.jpg) with AFNetworking's UIImageView category.

When I run the app on my iPad mini it crashes before it's able to display the image. I've created a sample app that does only that (load and display the image) in order to pinpoint the problem. [You can download it here.](http://cl.ly/3u3A2O2u2Q07)

### Problematic Image:

Here are my results on Instruments:

**Image:** http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/712130main_8246931247_e60f3c09fb_o.jpg (2.8MB)

[image: Instruments window for the app with the problematic image]

Using the Activity Monitor instrument I got this (seemingly absurd) memory result: **187MB real mem** / 535 virtual mem.

[image: Activity Monitor instrument for the problematic image]

### Working example:

Below are the results for another (bigger) image from the same site.

**Image:** http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/2013-3051.jpg (5MB)

[image: Instruments window for the app with the ok image]

And with Activity Monitor:

[image: Activity Monitor instrument for the ok image]

### Using the Simulator:

On the simulator, the first image does not crash the app, but it still has a weird pattern when compared to the working image:

Problematic Image:

[image: Instruments for simulator with problematic image]

Working Image:

[image: Instruments for simulator with ok image]

### Setup details:

- Deployment Target: 6.0
- Xcode Version: 4.6.3 (4H1503)
- iPad Mini iOS version: 6.1.3 (10B329)
- iPad Mini available disk space: 334MB out of 13.7GB capacity

I can't figure out what's wrong with the first image and why it's blowing up memory like that. I did notice it has a lot of pixels (12150×6075), although I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think the `UIImageView` category of `AFNetworking` is pretty weak, I think some (if not most) of the blame here rests with these huge images. Just because the JPEG files are reasonably sized, it doesn't mean that the resulting bitmaps (and thus, presumably, the resulting `UIImage` objects) are also reasonably sized.

That first image enjoys a lot of compression, and the resulting bitmap is at least an order of magnitude larger than the original JPEG. The second JPEG enjoys decent compression, too, but not nearly as dramatic as the first JPEG, and therefore the second JPEG's bitmap isn't as big as the first one's.

When dealing with images of this size, you'd either have the server resize them for screen resolutions, or employ some tiling solution. Devices of limited memory cannot be expected to handle images of these sizes gracefully.

Comment: I see. So is there no way to prevent these huge images from loading? We have server-side resizing, but it's a background job that can be run some minutes after creation. I'm worried the app will crash if the user accesses it in the meantime... (we delay image resizing and sending to S3 to prevent hanging)

Comment: Nevermind, we're storing the image's size on the server so I'll just not send images down to the app if they're bigger than 1024*1024 pixels or something. I've also found this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679457/app-crashing-when-using-large-images-on-ios-4-0

Comment: Ok, some hours later I found a way to prevent AFNetworking from loading large images. In the current master version, `AFImageRequestOperation.m` file, find `size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);` and jump out if the size is bigger than desired. Like so: `if (width * height > 2048*2048) { return nil; }`. This will return nil before the JPEG is converted to bitmap.